# no matching function for call to ‘Aws::S3::S3Client::S3Client(Aws::Auth::AWSCredentials, Aws::Client::ClientConfiguration&)’

Tags: c++, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk-cpp

main.cpp: In function ‘void downloadFile(const string&, const string&, std::ostream&)’:

main.cpp:23:95: error: no matching function for call to ‘Aws::S3::S3Client::S3Client(Aws::Auth::AWSCredentials, Aws::Client::ClientConfiguration&)’
Aws::S3::S3Client s3Client(Aws::Auth::AWSCredentials(ACCESS_KEY, SECRET_KEY), clientConfig);

In file included from main.cpp:3:

install/include/aws/s3/S3Client.h:100:9: note: candidate: ‘Aws::S3::S3Client::S3Client(const std::shared_ptrAws::Auth::AWSCredentialsProvider&, const Aws::Client::ClientConfiguration&, Aws::Client::AWSAuthV4Signer::PayloadSigningPolicy, bool, Aws::S3::US_EAST_1_REGIONAL_ENDPOINT_OPTION)’

S3Client(const std::shared_ptrAws::Auth::AWSCredentialsProvider& credentialsProvider,
install/include/aws/s3/S3Client.h:100:9: note:   candidate expects 5 arguments, 2 provided

```
#include <aws/lambda-runtime/runtime.h>
#include <aws/core/Aws.h>
#include <aws/s3/S3Client.h>
#include <aws/s3/model/GetObjectRequest.h>
#include <aws/core/auth/AWSCredentials.h>
#include <aws/core/client/ClientConfiguration.h>
//#include <aws/core/auth/AWSCredentialsProvider.h>

using namespace aws::lambda_runtime;

Aws::SDKOptions options;

static const char* ENDPOINT_URL = "endpoint";
static const char* ACCESS_KEY = "accesskey";
static const char* SECRET_KEY = "secretkey";

void downloadFile(const std::string& bucketName, const std::string& objectKey, std::ostream& outputStream) {
    Aws::Client::ClientConfiguration clientConfig;
    clientConfig.endpointOverride = ENDPOINT_URL;
    clientConfig.scheme = Aws::Http::Scheme::HTTP;
    clientConfig.connectTimeoutMs = 30000;
    clientConfig.requestTimeoutMs = 30000;
    clientConfig.region = "us-west-2";

    Aws::S3::S3Client s3Client(Aws::Auth::AWSCredentials(ACCESS_KEY, SECRET_KEY), clientConfig);

}
```

Comment: Can you point your finger at the exact line in the shown code which `#include`s the header file that defines the `Aws::Auth::AWSCredentials` class, according to aws's documentation which, despite not knowing much about this library, I found with a simple keyword search? This is a trick question, this `#include` is missing. P.S. whether a "fully qualified" name is used, or not, is utterly irrelevant, "incomplete type" means the type is not defined, fully qualified or not.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Thank you for your comment. I added AWSCredentials.h. But, I got no matching function for call to ‘Aws::S3::S3Client::S3Client(Aws::Auth::AWSCredentials, Aws::Client::ClientConfiguration&)’

Comment: Do not understand, "candidate expects 5 arguments, 2 provided"

Comment: Which of the six constructors of the `S3Client` class, documented in the [AWS SDK for C++ v1.11.156](https://sdk.amazonaws.com/cpp/api/LATEST/aws-cpp-sdk-s3/html/class_aws_1_1_s3_1_1_s3_client.html) are you trying to use? Your first argument is `AWSCredentials`, so this could only be either the second or the fifth constructor. But your second argument is `ClientConfiguration`, so the second constructor doesn't fit (it expects a `std::shared_ptr<S3EndpointProviderBase>` as its second argument), so it must be the fifth constructor. But then it needs more arguments: `PayloadSigningPolicy` etc.

Comment: Also, what version of AWS SDK for C++ are you using?

Comment: Here's a very high level overview of learning the AWS SDK: Step 1, spend 5-7 years learning core C++ fundamentals, to acquire expert level knowledge and understanding of this, the most complicated and hardest to use general purpose programming language in use today; Step 2: start learning boutique, specialized, highly technical libraries, like the AWS SDK, that require expert level knowledge of C++. The questions you're asking are typical of someone who's just learning C++, i.e. Step 1. Perhaps you want to focus a little bit more time on that, first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue as you did.
It appears that a constructor that used to exist previously has been modified in the latest SDK and default values have been removed.
Among the new ones, this is the one that closely matches. So you can either modify the constructor, or I would suggest you pass the values that it now requires.

```
S3Client(const Aws::Auth::AWSCredentials& credentials,
     const Aws::Client::ClientConfiguration& clientConfiguration,
     Aws::Client::AWSAuthV4Signer::PayloadSigningPolicy signPayloads,
     bool useVirtualAddressing,
     Aws::S3::US_EAST_1_REGIONAL_ENDPOINT_OPTION USEast1RegionalEndPointOption = Aws::S3::US_EAST_1_REGIONAL_ENDPOINT_OPTION::NOT_SET);
```

Use this to create the object instead.

```
Aws::S3::S3Client S3_Client = Aws::S3::S3Client(Aws::Auth::AWSCredentials(ACCESS_KEY, SECRET_KEY), clientConfig, Aws::Client::AWSAuthV4Signer::PayloadSigningPolicy::Never, true);
```